# Why is this Kotlin class property not shadowed by a method parameter?

Tags: kotlin

Looking at [this code in kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/67caffe88f5ad461713c1114a2f2c700a3eefe18/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/operators/Transform.kt#L44), I noticed something strange:

```kotlin
/**
 * Returns a flow containing the results of applying the given [transform] function to each value of the original flow.
 */
public inline fun <T, R> Flow<T>.map(crossinline transform: suspend (value: T) -> R): Flow<R> = transform { value ->
    return@transform emit(transform(value))
}
```

In the first line, the `transform` used is clearly `this.transform` ([defined here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/67caffe88f5ad461713c1114a2f2c700a3eefe18/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/operators/Emitters.kt#L19)). Shouldn't the `transform` declared in the method parameter have been used instead, as it is in the second line?

---

To test this, I wrote a small class which tries to mimc this behaviour:

```kotlin
// flow.kt

class Flow(val name: String) {
    public fun transform (transform: (Any) -> Unit): Flow {
        return Flow("transformed")
    }

    public fun emit(value: Any) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public fun map(transform: (Any) -> Unit): Flow = transform { value ->
         return@transform(emit(transform(value)))
    }
}
```

And I get the kind of warning I was expecting when I run `kotlinc flow.kt`:

```
flow.kt:12:54: error: type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Flow was expected
    public fun map(transform: (Any) -> Unit): Flow = transform { value ->
                                                     ^
flow.kt:12:66: error: cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
    public fun map(transform: (Any) -> Unit): Flow = transform { value ->
                                                                 ^
```

(Kotlin version as returned by `kotlinc -version` is "kotlinc-jvm 1.6.10 (JRE 17.0.1+1)")

So why is it that the code defined in kotlinx.coroutines works? If I understand Kotlin's name shadowing rules correctly it shouldn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `kotlinx.couroutines`, the `transform` parameter takes an argument of type `T`. Hence, `this.transform` is used when `transform` is called with a `(Any) -> Unit` argument.

In your example, the `transform` parameter takes an argument of type `Any`. A `(Any) -> Unit` is an `Any` and hence the parameter is being used instead of `this.transform`. Replacing `Any` with a type parameter will make your code compile too.

Comment: Thanks for the much needed hint Chandra (didn't expect to see you here!). This certainly moves things forward but I am not able to resolve this fully. Will accept your answer as soon as I can work out the issues on my end.

Comment: (Earlier comment was badly formatted so I moved the code to a gist). [This gist](https://gist.github.com/chaitanyagupta/4fb425c716305a9cec91b9c80ad41079) should make it clear that name shadowing depends on type specificity, as Chandra answers above.